# How to create a hook on a std::function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to decorate a `std::function` with "before" and "after" hooks.

I have some trouble figuring out the right syntax. This is what I have so far:

```
// create a "before" hook
template<typename Functor, typename Hook>
Functor hook_before(const Functor & original, Hook hook)
{
    // not legal, but illustrates what I want to achieve
    template<typename Args ...args> 
    return [=](Args ...args)
    {
        hook();
        original(args...);
    };
}
```

My sample application is on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZQCYi).

Can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: it should be `template<typename F1, typename F2, typename Hook> F1 hook(F2, Hook);`

Comment: @Abyx: But then the caller would have to specify `F1`. How would they do that?

Comment: @interjay, yep, then it should return `function<>`

Comment: @Abyx I thought it wasn't needed because the signature doesn't change. But you're actually right. The return type and input type can be different (std::function vs lambda-type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <class Hook, class ReturnType, class... ArgType>
std::function<ReturnType(ArgType...)> hook_before(
    const std::function<ReturnType(ArgType...)>& original, 
    Hook hook)
{
    return [=](ArgType... args){
        hook();
        return original(std::move(args)...);
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::function<int(int, int)> sum = [](int a, int b) { return a + b; };

    std::cout << sum(3, 4) << std::endl;

    auto myhook = []() { std::cout << "Calculating sum" << std::endl; };
    auto hooked_sum = hook_before(sum, myhook);
    std::cout << hooked_sum(3, 4) << std::endl;
}
```

The `hook_before` function accepts two functors, and returns another that accepts the same arguments as the first (the ArgType parameter pack), but calls `hook` first.

Answer (score 3):

Here goes (untested):

```
template <typename HOOK, typename RET, typename... ARGS>
struct BeforeHook {
    std::function<RET(ARGS...)> functor;
    HOOK hook;
    BeforeHook(blah) : blah {};

    RET operator()(ARGS&&... args) const {
        hook();
        return functor(args...);
    }
};

template <typename HOOK, typename RET, typename... ARGS>
BeforeHook<HOOK, RET, ARGS...> hook_before(const std::function<RET(ARGS...)> &original, HOOK hook) {
    return BeforeHook<HOOK, RET, ARGS...>(original, hook);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto hooked = hook_before(original_functor, hook_functor);
hooked(args_for_original_functor); // calls hook_functor, then original_functor
```

Or something along those lines. The original_functor needs to be convertible to `std::function`, but pretty much everything callable is. Both functors need to be cost-callable, but you could remove the `const` from `operator()` if you like.

If you want to experiment with returning a lambda rather than an instance of `BeforeHook`, use the same trick with the template arguments `RET` and `...ARGS`, and find out whether it's possible to use a template argument pack in a lambda:

```
template <typename HOOK, typename RET, typename... ARGS>
std::function<RET(ARGS...)> hook_before(const std::function<RET(ARGS...)> &original, HOOK hook) {
    return [=](ARGS&&... args) -> RET {
        hook();
        return original(args...);
    };
}
```

Either way, I think the key trick is using `std::function` in a template argument deduction to separate the return type from the arguments.

Comment: That would need an implicit conversion to a parameter which is being used for template parameter deduction, so it won't work (unless you explicitly specify all the template parameters - but I assume that's not what you had in mind).

Comment: @ymett: On the one hand, the questioner says "how to decorate a std::function with "before" and "after" hooks", so no conversion necessary, the input is a `function` already. On the other hand, I claimed it would work with a conversion, which is a bit feeble if the conversion has to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
template<typename Functor, typename Hook>
struct BeforeHooked
{
    Functor f;
    Hook hook;

    template<class... Args>
    typename std::result_of<F(Args&&...)>::type
    operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        hook();
        return f(std::forward<Args&&>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename Functor, typename Hook>
Functor hook_before(Functor f, Hook hook)
{
    return BeforeHooked{f, hook};
}
```

The code is untested, but assuming you have a compiler which can compile it, I think it should do what you want. Unlike the other answers, it can accept any functor, not just `std::function`, and if you give it a polymorphic functor it remains polymorphic.