# Redirect std::function() callable to custom handler in pre C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, hook, functor

I have something like this:

```
typedef std::function<void(int param1, int param2)> TheCallback;

void callTheCallback(TheCallback& theCallback) {
    theCallback(1, 2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    TheCallback cb = [](int a, int b) { 
        std::cout << "Param 1:" << a << ", Param 2:" << b << std::endl;
    };

    cb(100, 200);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is - what is the best way to hook std::function (or create a custom "backwards-compatible" std::function template) so that each time when such function is called it would also print some custom string (e.g. "Called") before doing anything else?

There is [nice solution for C++11 that uses variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911431/how-to-create-a-hook-on-a-stdfunction). So is there anything similar possible for C++0x (e.g. Visual Studio 2010)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a generic solution (supporting not just a function taking two ints and returning void) then you can use fake variadics to support a function taking any number of arguments up to an arbitrary fixed limit (this example supports up to three; VS2010's `std::function` can take up to ten).

```
void hook()
{
    std::cout << "Called\n";
}

template <typename R>
std::function<R()> wrap(std::function<R()> f)
{
    return [f]()->R { hook(); return f(); };
}

template <typename R, typename T0>
std::function<R(T0)> wrap(std::function<R(T0)> f)
{
    return [f](T0 v0)->R { hook(); return f(v0); };
}

template <typename R, typename T0, typename T1>
std::function<R(T0, T1)> wrap(std::function<R(T0, T1)> f)
{
    return [f](T0 v0, T1 v1)->R { hook(); return f(v0, v1); };
}

template <typename R, typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
std::function<R(T0, T1, T2)> wrap(std::function<R(T0, T1, T2)> f)
{
    return [f](T0 v0, T1 v1, T2 v2)->R { hook(); return f(v0, v1, v2); };
}

template <typename F>
typename func_traits<F>::wrap_type wrap(F f)
{
    return wrap(typename func_traits<F>::wrap_type(f));
}

int main()
{
    auto cb = [](int a, int b){ std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n"; };
    auto wrap_cb = wrap(cb);
    wrap_cb(1, 2);
}
```

It's not especially efficient, due to the two layers of `std::function` (each one incurs the cost of a `virtual` call), but should be sufficient for most purposes until you can upgrade to a better compiler.

EDIT: Thanks to Martinho for pointing out my glaring mistake. The above code is fixed by the addition of another `wrap()` overload, which uses the following type traits code to select the correct specialization of `std::function` for the deduced functor type:

```
template <typename T>
struct func_traits;

template <typename R>
struct func_traits<R()>
{
    typedef std::function<R()> wrap_type;
};
template <typename R, typename A0>
struct func_traits<R(A0)>
{
    typedef std::function<R(A0)> wrap_type;
};
template <typename R, typename A0, typename A1>
struct func_traits<R(A0, A1)>
{
    typedef std::function<R(A0, A1)> wrap_type;
};
template <typename R, typename A0, typename A1, typename A2>
struct func_traits<R(A0, A1, A2)>
{
    typedef std::function<R(A0, A1, A2)> wrap_type;
};

template <typename R>
struct func_traits<R(*)()> : func_traits<R()> {};
template <typename R, typename A1>
struct func_traits<R(*)(A1)> : func_traits<R(A1)> {};
template <typename R, typename A1, typename A2>
struct func_traits<R(*)(A1, A2)> : func_traits<R(A1, A2)> {};
template <typename R, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3>
struct func_traits<R(*)(A1, A2, A3)> : func_traits<R(A1, A2, A3)> {};
template <typename R, typename C>
struct func_traits<R(C::*)()> : func_traits<R()> {};
template <typename R, typename A1, typename C>
struct func_traits<R(C::*)(A1)> : func_traits<R(A1)> {};
template <typename R, typename A1, typename A2, typename C>
struct func_traits<R(C::*)(A1, A2)> : func_traits<R(A1, A2)> {};
template <typename R, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename C>
struct func_traits<R(C::*)(A1, A2, A3)> : func_traits<R(A1, A2, A3)> {};
template <typename R, typename C>
struct func_traits<R(C::*)() const> : func_traits<R()> {};
template <typename R, typename A1, typename C>
struct func_traits<R(C::*)(A1) const> : func_traits<R(A1)> {};
template <typename R, typename A1, typename A2, typename C>
struct func_traits<R(C::*)(A1, A2) const> : func_traits<R(A1, A2)> {};
template <typename R, typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename C>
struct func_traits<R(C::*)(A1, A2, A3) const> : func_traits<R(A1, A2, A3)> {};

template <typename T>
struct func_traits : func_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename T>
struct func_traits<T&> : func_traits<T> {};
template <typename T>
struct func_traits<T&&> : func_traits<T> {};
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e5aeca5b01a36e6

Comment: Excellent! That looks like exactly what I need. Basically, as I mentioned it in comment to another answer, what I need is some way to either "patch" the original std::function or to make seamless replacement of it to another one with different name (e.g. my_function<>) in which I should be able to install own hooks. Thanks a lot! I'll try this solution asap.

Comment: Er, this doesn't work. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b08d72591dfebf8e. Don't use `std::function` with template parameters like that. You can't get both type deduction and implicit conversions together.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes damn I need a break. Thanks for the hint, I fixed it.

Comment: Nice! That's much better than my own "fabrications" :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a wrapper for the callbacks that handles it like this:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void(int param1, int param2)> TheCallback;

class CallbackWrapper
{
public:
    CallbackWrapper(TheCallback callback)
        : m_callback(callback)
    {}

    void startCallback(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << "Called" << std::endl;
        m_callback(a, b);
    }

private:
    TheCallback m_callback;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TheCallback cb = [](int a, int b) { 
        std::cout << "Param 1:" << a << ", Param 2:" << b << std::endl;
    };

    CallbackWrapper testCallback(cb);

    testCallback.startCallback(11, 22);

    return system("pause");
}
```

You may even omit the local `cb`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CallbackWrapper testCallback([](int a, int b) { 
        std::cout << "Param 1:" << a << ", Param 2:" << b << std::endl;
    });

    testCallback.startCallback(11, 22);

    return system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I was looking for more generic solution like C++11 one (given at link). My problem is that I'd need to make a "transparent" replacement of std::function() everywhere in the code and defining custom wrappers for each case would cause too much of work.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with different options I came up to solution that replaces std::function<> with compatible template. Not perfect, but here what currently works for me:

```
template<class TFunc>
class hook_function : public std::function<TFunc>
{
public:
    typedef std::function<TFunc> FuncType;
    FuncType original;

    void hook()
    {
        std::cout << "Called." << std::endl;
    }

    hook_function() : FuncType()
    {}

    template<typename T>
    hook_function(T&& fn) 
        : original(std::forward<T>(fn)) 
        , FuncType(std::forward<T>(fn))
    {
    }

    hook_function(hook_function&& other) 
        : FuncType(static_cast<FuncType&&>(other))
    {
    }

    hook_function& operator=(hook_function&& other)
    {
        FuncType::operator=(static_cast<FuncType&&>(other));
        return *this;
    }

... insert more here ...

    void operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        hook();
        original(a, b);
    }

    void operator()(const std::string s)
    {
        hook();
        original(s);
    }
};
```